# overflow: hidden and ellipsis not working with background-image before text to hide

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have some text I want to have hidden with ellipsis. But when there is a background image in a div before the text, it doesn't work, https://jsfiddle.net/ypbgkrod/6/,

```css
.block {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 0.3em;
}

.summary-content {
  margin-left: 0.2rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.summary-content .description {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.ellipsis {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="thumb" role="img" style="background-image: url(''); height: 73px; width: 130px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="summary-content" data-permlink="i-want-more-of-my-life">
    <div class="description">
      <p class="ellipsis">Some random text that is long, long…Some random text that is long, long…Some random text that is long, long…Some random text that is long, long…</p>
    </div>
    <div class='slider'>
      Need this to not overflow hide. Need this to not overflow hide. Need this to not overflow hide.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Removing the `<div class="thumbnail">` section has the text ellipsis and overflow hidden works, with the part for the slider working as well by not being hidden.

This isn't the full original problem, as I tried to resolve the issue below by doing the above, but I couldn't get the overflow ellipsis to work on the text required.

Context of original issue:

The original code was that I have a pop up div with a Slider that needs to go over the overflow div, but it doesn't and gets cut off when the `.block` div ends. Removing overflow hidden on the `.summary-content` div has the Slider pop up fully, but then the ellipsis doesn't work.

The text ellipsis was working WITH the image, but it's when there was no extra `<div class="description">`. Problem is it was cutting off the Slider div with the overflow hidden on the `summary-content` div which the slider was also in.

```css
.block {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 0.3em;
}

.summary-content {
  margin-left: 0.2rem;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ellipsis {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="thumb" role="img" style="background-image: url(''); height: 73px; width: 130px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="summary-content" data-permlink="i-want-more-of-my-life">
    <p class="ellipsis">Some random text that is long, long…Some random text that is long, long…Some random text that is long, long…Some random text that is long, long…</p>
    <div class='slider'>slider</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So when I added the extra encapsulation (description) for the `<p class="ellipsis">`, the `<div class='slider'>` isn't being hidden anymore, but the ellipsis doesn't work. I just wanted to let you know that the ellipsis not working is resolved when I don't have the `description` div, but the overflow is hiding part of the Slider popup that's within the `summary-content` div, and I can't have that.

If you could get the first HTML and CSS to hide the overflow on the ellipsis text, and not be applied to the slider, that would be the solution I'm looking for, as the second part of code doesn't show the whole problem fully to have the problem show up in a jsfiddle.

Thanks!

Comment: add `min-width: 0` to `summary-item` in the *first code* https://jsfiddle.net/pr2zhj58/

Comment: Thank you :) Since you answered 2 mins before the other answer, please put your answer to receive the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: Np, you can mark any of the below answers, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `min-width: 0;` in `summary-content` **CSS**. Thanks

```
.summary-content {
    min-width: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 divs `.thumbnail` and `.summary-content`. If you put width 100% for summary-content then it will go out of the screen so I added the below CSS

```
.summary-content {
  width: 80%;
}
```

```css
.block {
  display: flex;
}

.summary-content {
  width: 80%;
}

.summary-content .description {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.ellipsis {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="thumb" role="img" style="background-image: url(''); height: 73px; width: 130px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="summary-content" data-permlink="i-want-more-of-my-life">
    <div class="description">
      <p class="ellipsis">Some random text that is long, long…Some random text that is long, long…Some random text that is long, long…Some random text that is long, long…</p>
    </div>
    <div class='slider'>
    Need this to not overflow hide. Need this to not overflow hide. Need this to not overflow hide.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```